# Changed & Improved passing data from WebServlet to a WebService

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I'm pretty new to writing Servlet and REST Services, but now i'm at a problem that I'm not sure if i'm doing it correctly. My Service look like this:

```
@POST
@Produces ("application/json")
@Path ("/register")
public String register(
    @FormParam("name") String name,
    @FormParam("username") String username,
    @FormParam("password") String password,
    @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {

    if( this.user_taken(username) ) return "USERNAME_TAKEN";
    User user = new User(name,username,password);

    .....

    return mapper.writeValueAsString(user);

}
```

So as you can see the `Service` takes care of doing the back end (database and creating user) the `Servlet` on the other hand is in charge of taking request from the form, properly validating and passing it to the `Service`. Servlet Code:

```
... validate user input form ...

ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource service = client.resource("http://localhost/Jaba");

String map = mapper.writeValueAsString(request.getParameterMap());
MultivaluedMap<String, String> obj = mapper.readValue(map, MultivaluedMap.class);

String result = 
    service.path("api").path("register")
        .accept("application/json")
        .post(String.class, obj);
```

As you can see the Client (Servlet) has to do a lot of nasty work, to pass data to the Service. How can this be changed/improved/optimized or better yet refactored ? I'm trying to follow best practices and how it would be in a real life example.

Comment: can anyone explain to me why this is doesn't actually belong on stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I might do:

Instead of doing

```
String result = 
    service.path("api").path("register")
        .accept("application/json")
        .post(String.class, obj);
```

I would do something more like creating a DTO object, filling it out and then passing it to your service. This is then were you would apply an aspect along with JSR validation and annotations (you can do this on what you have but it won't be nearly so nice) on the client call.

example:

```
@Aspect
public class DtoValidator {

    private Validator validator;

    public DtoValidator() {
    }

    public DtoValidator(Validator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public void doValidation(JoinPoint jp){
        for( Object arg : jp.getArgs() ){
            if (arg != null) {
                Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validator.validate(arg);
                if( violations.size() > 0 ){
                    throw buildError(violations);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static BadRequestException buildError( Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations ){
        Map<String, String> errorMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for( ConstraintViolation error : violations ){
            errorMap.put(error.getPropertyPath().toString(), error.getMessage());
        }
        return new BadRequestException(errorMap);
    }
}
```

You can annotatively declare you aspect or you can do it in config (makes it reusable). As such:

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:aspect id="dtoValidator" ref="dtoValidator" order="10">
        <aop:before method="doValidation" pointcut="execution(public * com.mycompany.client.*.*(..))"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Now you can have a DTO like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class LoginRequest extends AbstractDto{

    @NotNull
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    private LoginRequest() {
    }

    public LoginRequest(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

}
```

When it fails those `@NotNull` checks you will get something like this:

```
{
   "message":"{username=must not be null",
   "httpStatusCode":400,
   "httpMessage":"Bad Request",
   "details":{
      "username":"must not be null"
   }
}
```

Then use a RestOperation client as such

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations restClient ...
restClient.postForObject(URL,new Dto(...),args);
```

Place the aspect around this `restClient` and you're golden (and, actually for good measure, on your service calls too).

Comment: I think this maybe an overkill for this small project? Passing an object to the service maybe a great idea but would not really work out nicely if the client wanted to use javascript as the client. The examples look great but not what i'm looking for and honestly a bit advanced for me. I was thinking a long the lines of changing it to pass a JSON string to the server instead of all the @FormParam or something, can you still help?

Comment: POJO plain old java objects are hardly advanced. just a place holder with some behavior (methods)

Comment: @Jessica , you are mistaken about using this with Javascript. This actually works really nice for Java script. JSON = Javascript Object Notation. You can tell your webservice Content-Type: application/json and your WS controller will do all the marshalling. 

It may seem daunting but really, it's ideal and (now that I have given you copious details and sample code) easy. 

You get to learn about Spring aspects (Aspect oriented programming in general) and you get build in validation. Also, this is a generalized solution. From this point forward ALL calls that match the aspect pattern benefit